# TestFlight - Removing/Disabling app from tester's devices

Tags: ios, testflight

I was wondering if you can disable or delete (already installed) app from tester's devices in TestFlight, since expiring the build or removing testers will leave the app installed until it automatically expires after 90 days testing period.

The problem is that I submitted the app for review in order to enable external testing, and during this period I would want to disable the app in internal tester's devices. I want to do this because I'm using Firebase for back-end with the free plan, which has a limit for transactions. So, I don't want the testers to use the resources while the app is being reviewed and tested by Apple.

Of course, I could notify these users to not use the app in the meantime, but I'm curious to know if this is possible, because it would be helpful in some other cases too.

***NOTE***: I know this question has been answered, but it's from 2012, and I want to know if anything changed.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Removal of TestFlight apps?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10128162/removal-of-testflight-apps)

Comment: AFAIK the situation has not changed - you can't disable or delete an app your testers have installed.

Comment: This is the question I was talking about at the end of my question.